# Error: "Excess elements in char array initializer"

Tags: arrays, c, c-strings, string-comparison

As you can see, I am trying to check whether the element entered by the user is present in my array or not. But the following errors occur on the line on which `arr` is declared and defined:

```
1)[Error] excess elements in char array initializer 
2)[Error] (near initialization for 'arr')
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char word;
    scanf("%d",&word);
    char arr[7]={"break", "case", "continue", "default", "else", "defer", "for"};
    int i,n=7;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(word==arr[i]){
            printf("Keyword Found");
        }
        else{
            printf("Keyword Not Found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `arr` is supposed to be an array of characters, but the initializer contains strings, not characters.

Comment: You don't seem to understand the difference between characters and strings in C. I suggest you reread your tutorial.

Comment: To compare strings you use `strcmp()`, not `==`

Comment: The `%d` directive is not appropriate for reading data into `word`, regardless of whether it is a `char` or a `char *`.  Possibly you want to make `word` an *array* of `char`, and to use a `%s` directive with that.

Comment: The C FAQ list can be very helpful with *all* the problems you are running into here. In particular, see http://c-faq.com/charstring/stringeq.html http://c-faq.com/charstring/assign.html http://c-faq.com/charstring/strlitinit.html http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Comment: Besides all the above issues, your code would print "Keyword not found" multiple times.

Comment: An improvement on this line in the answers, `const char *arr[] = {...};`. You don't have to, and shouldn't really, specify array dimensions if you don't have to. You can use `sizeof arr / sizeof *arr` to get the number of items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `arr` is an array of `char`'s, but the initialization list consists of an array of string literals. A string literal can be used to initialize an array of `char`'s, but that is not what `arr` is, hence the compiler producing an error regarding `excess elements`. These statements would be valid, as the initializer contains a single string literal:

```
char arr[6] = { "break" };
```

or rather

```
char arr[6] = "break";
```

Change `arr` to be an array of an array of `char`'s and the code will compile:

```
char arr[7][9]={"break", "case", "continue", "default", "else", "defer", "for"};
```

These are 7 elements of which the longest has the length 9: "continue". Note that this number is the 8 letters of the word, and 1 for the null-terminator (`\0`).
Another way of initializing `arr` is this:

```
char *arr[7] = { /* ... */ };
```

In this case, `arr` contains 7 `char` pointers to the 7 strings (which exist elsewhere in memory).

Here is your full program with line-by-line corrections and suggestions:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>                         // Add stdio header for scanf and printf
#include <string.h>                        // Add string header for strcmp

int main(void){                            // Add "void" for a correct main signature
    char word[64];                         // Needs to be a character array, not a single character
    scanf("%64s", word);                   // Needs to read a string of max 64 characters, not an integer

                                           // Next line needs to be a 2D array: it is an array of character arrays

    char arr[7][9]={"break", "case", "continue", "default", "else", "defer", "for"};

    int n=7;                               // Declare variables on separate lines
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){                  // Declare/define i within the for-loop to reduce its scope
        if(!strcmp(word, arr[i])){         // Replace == by strcmp
            printf("Keyword Found\n");     // Add newline character for nicer output
        }
        else{
            printf("Keyword Not Found\n"); // Add newline character for nicer output
        }
    }
}
```

Note that, to make it work, also the type of `word`, the arguments to `scanf` and the string comparison were changed. The `==` compares if the two pointers (to the two strings) are equal (in other words, the two pointers point to the same location), but does not compare the contents of the two strings. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) for more info `strcmp`. Note that it returns `0` if the strings are identical.

The next step may be to scan the list of keywords to detect whether a match was found and only print one "found / not found" statement at the end. This can be done by using a boolean:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char word[64];
    scanf("%64s", word);
    char arr[7][9]={"break", "case", "continue", "default", "else", "defer", "for"};
    int n=7;
    bool keywordFound = false;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(!strcmp(word, arr[i])){
            keywordFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (keywordFound)
        printf("Keyword Found\n");
    else
        printf("Keyword Not Found\n");
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help Yun. But can we use 1D array instead of 2D array? And can you please suggest me the solution without using bool header file? Cause I don't have any knowledge about bool header file.

Comment: @VaibhavKatre Using booleans isn't that difficult, it's almost only a `typedef` for an `int`. If you want to do without them, just do _not_ include the header file and use an `int` directly, and use `0` for "false" and any non-zero value for "true". E.g.: `int keywordFound = 0;` The if-statement will work as it is. Does this help?

Comment: @VaibhavKatre Using a 1D is possible using a trick, but not recommended as the data is inherently 2D. If you really want to use a 1D array, you could define it as `"char *arr = "break\0case\0continue\0.....";` and use indexing, e.g. write `arr[6]` to "jump" to the word "case". The function `strcmp` will read until it finds the null-terminator `\0`, so it won't go into the next word. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

The size of an object of the type `char` is always equal to `1`. So such an object as declared in the program with the name `word`

```
char word;
```

can not contain a string. Strings have types of character arrays.

Moreover this call of `scanf`

```
scanf("%d",&word);
```

does not make a sense and invokes undefined behavior due to using the incorrect conversion specifier `%d` with an object of the type `char`.

You need to declare a character array to input a string as for example

```
char word[10];
```

and call `scanf` like

```
scanf("%9s", word);
```

Also the array declaration is incorrect. The array does not contain 7 characters. Its initializers are string literals that have types of character arrays.

You should write

```
char * arr[7]={"break", "case", "continue", "default", "else", "defer", "for"};
```

or even it is better to write

```
const char * arr[7]={"break", "case", "continue", "default", "else", "defer", "for"};
```

To compare two strings you need to use standard string function `strcmp` declared in the header `<string.h>` as for example

```
if ( strcmp( word, arr[i] ) == 0 )
{
    // two strings are equal each other
}
else
{
    // two strings are unequal
}
```

Also there is no sense to output the message

```
printf("Keyword Not Found");
```

for each unequal string in the array.

The loop can be rewritten at least the following way

```
int i = 0, n = 7;

while ( i < n && strcmp( word, arr[i] ) != 0 ) i++;

if ( i != n )
{
    printf("Keyword Found");
}
else
{
    printf("Keyword Not Found");
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const char * arr[] = 
    {
        "break", "case", "continue", "default", "else", "defer", "for"
    };
    const size_t N = sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr );
    
    char word[10] = "";
    
    scanf( "%9s", word );
    
    size_t i = 0;
    
    while ( i < N && strcmp( word, arr[i] ) != 0 ) i++;

    if ( i != N )
    {
        printf( "Keyword Found at Position %zu\n", i );
    }
    else
    {
        puts( "Keyword Not Found" );
    }
        
    return 0;
}
```

If to enter for example the string `"continue"` then the program output is

```
Keyword Found at Position 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Vlad. Your answer helped me a lot.

Comment: can you please explain why have you used this in your code "const size_t N = sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr );"

Comment: @VaibhavKatre The array arr is declared without specifying explicitly the number of elements in the array.  The number of elements in this case is equal to the number of initializers. You can include more initializers in the declaration of the array. In this case teh array will have more elements. To determine the resulting number of elements the expression  sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr ) is used. The first sizeof gives the size of the whole array. The second sizeof gives the size of elements of the array. So the quotient of division gives the number of elements in the array.

Comment: Can we initialize N=sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr ), without using const size_t?

Comment: can you please explain me the concept of using %9s and %zu? because till now I have only used and seen %s not %9s and %zu. It would be great if you explain me these things too! Thanks Vlad!!1

Comment: @VaibhavKatre The conversion specifier zu is used for objects of the type size_t. 9s means to enter a string containing 9 characters to prevent writing outside the character array used as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Strings in C are arrays of `char`, and their max length should be specified. So the declarations for your string variables should be as follows. I'm assuming strings with length 9 plus the null character `\0`.

```
char word[10];  // string with 9 characters plus termination character \0
char arr[7][10] = {"break", "case", "continue", "default", "else", "defer", "for"};  // array with 7 strings of size 10 (9 chars plus \0)
```

Also, strings should be compared using the [`strcmp`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm) function from the `string.h` lib instead of `==`. The latter only compares the memory address of the string while `strcmp` compares the characters of each string.

Further reading about C strings: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm

Answer (score 1):

```
char arr[7]={"break", "case", "continue", "default", "else", "defer", "for"};
```

your arr is a character array not array of strings. You can make an array of strings using concept of structure.Like this,

```
char arr[10];
struct arr_str{
    char arr[10];
};
int main(){
    struct arr_str array[7];   // array of strings.
    return 0;
}
```

Or you can just simply also make a two dimensional array of characters (array of array).

```
char arr[7][10];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have more errors than lines here:

1. `char arr[7]=` => `char *arr[7]=`
2. To compare strings you need to use [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) function
3. If you want to [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) string use `%s` format specifier.
4. To store the string you need the `char` array:

Instead of

```
char word;
scanf("%d",&word);
```

do

```
char word[10];
scanf("%9s",word);
```